# How to populate data with haveInDatabase in _beforeSuite in Codeception

Tags: php, codeception

What I am trying to do is to insert some data to the Database before the suite starts. The dump is a clean Db and I have multiple suites that will need different starting data.

this is my code right now

```js
namespace Helper;

// here you can define custom actions
// all public methods declared in helper class will be available in $I



use Codeception\TestInterface;

class Contacts extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public $started = false;
    public function _beforeSuite($settings = [])
    {

        parent::_beforeSuite($settings); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        $dba = $this->getModule('Db');


        $dba->haveInDatabase('table1',array('is_published'=>'1','created_by'=>'1',
            'created_by_user'=>'Automated User'));




    }
```

I don't get any errors but the data is not there when codeception starts

Answer (score 0):

Have you got `cleanup: true` in parameters of Db modules?

It cleans data before each test, so in order to keep data inserted in _beforeSuite, you have to disable cleanup by changing it to `cleanup: false`.